# Draw table in following format with colspan and rowspan in HTML?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to draw a table in following format:

[image: table that I wanted to draw]

But it's not displaying properly. It's inserting some rows after the last column.
How can I fix the HTML?

```
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Client ID</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Trade ID</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Symbol</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Average Price</th>
    <th colspan="3">DTD</th>
    <th colspan="3">MTD</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Net YTD</th>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.clientID}" /><br></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.tradeID}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.symbol}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.averagePrice}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.DTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.MTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.YTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.DTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.MTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.YTD}" /></td>
    <td><core:out value="${orderBookData.YTD}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: plz show us how you tried it in HTML and expln where you are stk.

Comment: What's your HTML code so far?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I posted a link to it! You have your answer now, but try to use it next time you have a question. It is very simple to use and can help you and everyone else on SO give and get better and quicker answers.

Comment: ya got jsfiddle and its use.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header row is perfectly accurate. However, you need to account for the extra rows and columns with your subsequent `<td>` tags. Since columns 1-4 and 7 are `rowspan="2"`, you need a second `<tr>` with two `<td>` tags to account for the extra cells needed in columns 5-6. Further, since you want three cells each under columns 5-6, you need to triple this number. Thus six would be needed:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

All subsequent rows below that will need 11 `<td>` tags, since you must account for all seven columns plus the four extra cells.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aj5k7/2/

Tutorial on the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/tables.php/